# how to communicate with system pop-up using selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

im using selenium for automation, and in some part of the process im automation I get a system-pop up like this:

[image]

And I want to click on "ok", how can I do this?

thanks

ANSWER:

[How to handle Javascript Alert/pop up window in selenium webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27841988/how-to-handle-javascript-alert-pop-up-window-in-selenium-webdriver)

Answer (score 0):

[Autoit](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) provides windows GUI interaction.

Comment: I want to use selenium

Comment: @Joe Selenium doesn't have this option.

Comment: cant i just click ENTER? cause the ok is defaultivly selected, i just need to hit enter

Comment: @Joe I don't know, try `Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.KeyDown(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Enter);` Or `action.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Enter).Perform();`

Comment: This is C# syntax, similar to java and python

Comment: thanks bro got an answer, its possible in selenium, check out the question I added answer

Comment: @Joe Cool. I was under the impression it was windows alert.

Answer (score 0):

Try AppleScript on macOS. It can handle the system pop-up.

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "NotificationCenter"
    click last item of windows
end tell
```

The example is how to click the system pop-up.

Maybe you can modify it for using on your case.