# How to handle javascript alert message popup in selenium web driver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

How to handle javascript alert message popup in selenium web driver
i need selenium web driver code please

how to click on ok button using selenium web driver

[image]

Comment: a simple google on how to handle a alert in selenium gave me following results.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27841988/how-to-handle-javascript-alert-pop-up-window-in-selenium-webdriver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this: `driver.switchTo().alert().accept();`

to accept the `Javascript` alert. This might help you more: [Handling Javascript alerts](http://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/how-to-handle-javascript-alerts-confirmation-prompts)

Comment: i did that but 
in my web site when i am changing year than showing first alert message are you sure? and then after showing another popup which shown in above screen shot
so for first one popup i did and it works but second alert message
doesnt work driver.switchTo().alert().accept(); code

Comment: Make sure you have enough wait between the first `switchTo()` and the second one.

Comment: Between the two `switchTO()`, just add `Thread.sleep(3000);` and see what happens.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48800641/how-to-select-option-using-ul-and-li-css-in-selenium-web-driver-code-please?noredirect=1#comment84607843_48800641

can you please answer for this question?